# Where have all the item set bonuses been moved to in TF2?

Tags: team-fortress-2

Semi-recently, all the bonuses formerly associated with item sets (Saharan Spy, Croc-O-Style Kit, Tank Buster, Gas Jockey, et cetera) have either been moved onto items within that set, or removed completely from the game.

Which of these item set bonuses are still around, and what items now give a player these bonuses, if any?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sets which have had their bonuses changed are:
Scout (The Special Delivery- Shortstop, Mad Milk, Holy Mackerel): Formerly +25hp, shortstop now provides +20% healing.

Soldier (The Tank Buster- Black Box, Battalion's Backup): Formerly 20% sentry resistance. Backup now provides 50% sentry resistance when the buff is active.

Pyro (The Attendant- Degreaser, Powerjack): Formerly +10% speed, 10% bullet vulnerability. Powerjack now provides +15% speed, +20% vulnerability when active.

Heavy (The Hibernating Bear- Brass Beast, Warrior's Spirit): Formerly +5% crit resistance. Doesn't even provide a calling card now.

Demoman  (The Expert's Ordnance- Loch and Load, Ullapool Caber): Formerly 10% fire resistance. Doesn't even provide a calling card now.

Engineer never actually had a set bonus.

Medic (The Medieval Medic- Crusader's Crossbow, Amputator): Formerly +1hp/sec. Amputator now provides +3hp/sec while active.

Sniper (The Croc-o-Style kit- Sydney Sleeper, Darwin's Danger Shield, Bushwacka): Formerly provided immunity to headshots. Shield now provides bullet resistance.

Spy (The Saharan Spy- L'Etranger, Your Eternal Reward): Formerly provided silent decloaking and longer cloak blink time. Now provides particle effects on taunt.

Comment: L'Etranger also provides +40% cloak duration. I think this is the spiritual successor to silent decloaking.